# Isn't vector.at(vector.size()-1) better than vector.back() in case it's empty?

Tags: c++

Just in case the vector is empty, (unexpected, exceptional case)

cppreference says on [vector::back()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back):

> Calling back on an empty container causes **undefined behavior**.

But on [vector::at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at):

> If pos is not within the range of the container, an exception of type **std::out_of_range** is thrown.

So if the container is empty, it's UB if the `back()` was used, but `std::out_of_range` is thrown if the `at()` was used.

Then, isn't it better to use `vector.at(vector.size()-1)` instead of `vector.back()` just in case it's empty?

(Since `vector.size()` will return `size_t` which is unsigned, `vector.size()-1` would be some number like 18446744073709551615, so maybe `vector.at(static_cast<int>(vector.size())-1)` would be even better, strictly speaking.)

Comment: The best would be not to access the element at index `vector.size()-1` without checking that size > 0.

Comment: Well let me ask you: If you vector is empty, is that an exceptional case or something that is easy to handle and somewhat expected?

Comment: Even better is not doing either, when the vector is empty.

Comment: @NathanOliver I was considering an exceptional case, somewhat *un*expected.

Comment: If it is an exceptional case then throwing an exception is a good idea IMHO.

Comment: You should have CI tests running with container bounds checks. Then, use `v.back()` if you think the vector can't be empty, or `v.at(v.size() - 1)` if you think it can, and an exception is an acceptable reaction.

Comment: In practice, the circumstances of a program's logic almost always results in a situation where you can trust that an index will be valid (in which case an `assert` is sufficient to find logic errors). You only need `at` when the argument is coming from an unreliable source which is unchecked, such as unchecked user input. But this is usually not a situation you want to find yourself in. To me, any use of `at` is a red flag.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks. Could you explain a bit more why using `at` is bad?

Comment: @starriet The difference between at and operator[] is that at performs a boundary check. But in most practical cases this check isn't necessary and you might be paying a performance cost for no benefit whatsoever. The reason I consider it a red flag is it either isn't providing a benefit (in which case it should be changed) or it is providing a benefit and the code is relying on unchecked inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already know that the vector is empty you would not call either of them.

**at()**

When you do not know whether the vector is empty and you are not certain that the index you are using is a valid one then you can use `at`. Though most of the time you should know already that the index is valid (for example there is almost never a good reason to call `at` inside a loop, when iterating elements).

`at` should be used only rarely. Most of the time you should know already if there is an element or not and then act accordingly. Checking bounds has a cost, and exceptions are for exceptional cases, they should not be used for control flow.

For example

```
 int foo(const std::vector<int>& x) { return x.back(); }
```

You can replace `back` with `at(x.size()-1)` but whether this is the right choice needs to be determined from case to case. Other alternatives include (non exhaustive, no particular order):

- `x` being non empty is a precondition of `foo`. Nothing has to be changed. Using `back` is fine. If someone does not respect preconditions they get what they deserve.
- `foo` could return a `std::optional<int>`. Then no exception is needed. Instead `if (x.empty()) return {};` can be added as first line. Once `back` is called, the vector is already known to be not empty.
- `foo` could throw an exception when `x` is empty. Then you should consider what exception to throw. Throwing a generic `out_of_bounds` exception may be inappropriate. Maybe you want to throw a `foo_has_an_issue` exception and add as first line `if (x.empty()) throw foo_has_an_issue{};`

**back()**

`back()` is undefined when the vector is empty. You need to check if there is an element before calling it.

**size()-1**

`size()` returns an unsigned. When the vector is empty then `size()-1` is a large integer, it is certainly not a valid index.

Answer (score 4):

*"better"* depends on the situation.

`back()` exists for those cases when you *know* that the `vector` is "`not v.empty()`". In those cases, using `at()` is just wasting resources. This is a quite common case.

`at()` on the other hand can be useful when you don't know or care if the supplied index is within bounds. You may have an exception handler installed already so you let that deal with the exceptional event that the index is out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that the vector is not empty before you try to access the back element:

```
int x = 0;

if (!v.empty())
{
  x = v.back();
}
```

In the above case the behavior is that `x` will equal:

- zero if `v` is empty, and
- `v.back()` if `v` is not empty.

If you expect that the vector might be empty sometimes in the normal execution of your program, then it should be handled in a similar way to above. You have something defined for `x` to equal if `v` is empty.

However, if v should never be empty (i.e.: `v` being empty represents abnormal behavior) then you should throw your own exception at that point. Rather than relying on `std::out_of_range`, you can throw something that makes it more obvious what the problem is (i.e.: the problem is that `v` was empty, not that an index was out of range).

Comment: A flaw with this is `0` could be a value in the vector so you can't know if `x` is `0` for an error or is an actual `0` value.

Comment: Of course, but you have to handle the case somehow. The point is to have a defined value to assign to x in the case that the vector is empty. Maybe you want it to equal 0, maybe you want it to equal 42, it would all depend on what you are using this to do.

Comment: this is potentially hiding a bug. Either `v` can be empty in this code, then this should be considered from the start and there must be an alternative to assign to `x`. Or, the vector is assumed to be not empty, and thats the dangerous case, because if due to a bug it is empty, you will never notice

Comment: My point is that if the values in the vector can use the entire range of the element types (so for `int` a value in `[INT_MIN, INT_MAX]`) then you can't know if `x` has a valid value or an error value after you do your if statement.

Comment: `at` has a way to handle the unexpected empty vector. Sorry, but I do not see the point you are trying to make in favour of `back` here

Comment: The point it that is not an error case if you define it like this. If it is an error case for the vector to be empty then throw the exception.

Comment: ok, its half me having misread and half me still not agreeing :)

Comment: `auto val = not v.empty() ? std::optional{v.back()} : std::nullopt;` ? :-)

Comment: Yeah that would probably be better

Comment: @NathanOliver I think the point of this answer is to present a hypothetical situation where `0` happens to be a valid error value, providing a counter-example to the assumption that `at(v.size()-1);` is better. I don't think it is intended to be taken as a general alternative.

Comment: test followed by access is not great if you are dealing with MT code